# Angular Js - Routing Issue with different old version

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJS and was looking at the "Miguel Castro–AngularJS for ASP.NET MVC Developers" sample downloaded from "http://www.melvicorp.com/downloads.html".

When running the code sample of project 2 (AngularRouting) from Miguel's sample with new version of AngularJs (installed using NuGet), the routing doesn't work and it gives the following error:

> [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$location/nobase

If I replace the new version of AngularJs Script files with older ones from Miguel's sample project, it works just fine.

I has clearly something to do with version, but what it is exactly?

Thanks

Comment: I just downloaded it and tested; Project 2 AngularRouting is working fine with Angular 1.5.6. Could you create [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: I've re-produced the issue and uploaded my project on DropBox. Here is the link.: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi6ig4pr5edlm7d/AngularJsRoutingForPlunker.rar?dl=0.